# Как узнать сгенерировался ли нативный код для метода?

Tags: c#

Допустим есть класс и метод:

```
class MyClass
{
   public void Method()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
   }
}
```

Как узнать, был ли уже сгенерирован нативный код для этого метода?

Comment: "Нативный метод" => "Определенный в родителе"?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков нет, C# генерирует машинный код в рантайме и я хочу узнать был ли он уже сгенерирован для конкретного метода или еще нет

Comment: Код компилится при первом вызове метода. Если метод был вызван хоть раз - код есть, если нет - кода нет.

Comment: Вопрос интересный, но зачем такое понадобилось? / Есть ngen, есть AOT, есть tiered compilation. В общем, всё сложно.

Comment: @aepot да, вот это я и хочу узнать, был ли вызван метод

Comment: Есть консольная тулза для Developer консоли, в которой можно подключиться к процессу и сдампить любой метод из сборки, но я хоть убей не помню, как она называется. Вспомню - отпишусь. Опять же, код может быть скомпилирован в AOT, тогда все такие проверки ничего не скажут о факте вызова метода.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я хочу сделать либу которая будет заменять один метод на другой (делаю jmp на адрес другого метода). У меня получилось это сделать, но только если методы уже были сгенерированы в нативный код (можно и не вызывать методы на самом деле, `RuntimeHelpers.PrepeareMethod()` делает это), но я хочу, чтобы методы принимали уже jited методы и кидать исключение в случае если метод не был jited

Comment: @aepot есть `Debug` -> `Windows` -> `Disassembly`, может вы это имеете в виду?

Comment: Нет, это не в студии, я из developer консоли гонял, когда SIMD разбирал. Там тулза какой-то командой ставится, затем аргументами цепляется к запущенному процессу по его номеру с запросом кода из метода в тех же аргументах.

Comment: [JIT Tracing ETW Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/jit-tracing-etw-events). Покопаться в ETW - там очень много типов событий.

Comment: [Method ETW Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/method-etw-events)

Comment: [Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) - набор полезных утилит. Возможно, @aepot использовал ProcDump оттуда?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov неа, не его, но из головы напрочь улетело, что именно. Вспомню - напишу ответ, потому что оно делает ровно то, что автор хочет. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance_improvements_in_net_7/ вот здесь еще много полезного про JITting

Comment: @aepot возможно история браузера по ключевым словам SIMD поможет?